# Is it painting or paintings when we refer to it as a form of art?

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

Cinematography is a form of visual arts with motion pictures.
Photography is a form of visual arts with static pictures.

But how does one refer to a form of visual arts that consists of paintings created by famous artists? As in `живопись` in Russian.

Is it **painting** or **paintings**?

To expand on this, in Russian language a word "painting" means both `картина` и `живопись`, which can be confusing. I.e. a "painting" as a single object of art and as an entire set of all paintings that ever existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two definitions of the word *painting* in the [Cambrige Online  Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/painting), The first is

> a picture made using paint

which has as one of its examples

> *an exhibition of 19th-century French painting*

and the second is

> the skill or activity of making a picture or putting paint on a wall

With an example

> *We were taught painting and drawing at art college*

When we speak of the art works consisting of painted images produced by an artist who worked or works in multiple media (Leonardo da Vinci for example) we can refer to it either as "the paintings of Leonardo" or "the painting of Leonardo". In the first case we are talking about the collection of images but in the second we are talking about the painted images as a whole which can also be considered as the product of the activity (like the "we were taught painting" example above.

When we speak of the body of work of an artist who worked almost exclusively in paint (Van Gough for example) we almost always use the singular form which refers to the body of work as a whole or to the activity as a whole by saying "The painting of Van Gough"

The only problem with doing this is that it can be ambiguous with the alternative meaning of "the painting which has the artist as a subject" For instance "The paining of Van Gough with his ear bandaged"

In conclusion it is possible to use either the singular or the plural depending on the context. For instance we can say "the majority of the paintings of Van Gough were inherited and later sold by his brother Theo" because we are talking about the artifacts and not about the body of work as a conceptual whole.

Comment: Thank you so much for your elaborate reply!

Comment: Is "The paining of Van Gough with his ear bandaged" intentional?

Comment: In 'We were taught painting and drawing at art college', 'painting' is not a singular usage but a singular-form non-count usage. In 'He's been working on that painting on the easel for weeks now', 'painting' is the singular count usage. He might be working on 2 / 7 / 43 paintings (plural count usage) next week.

Comment: @StuartF No, it must have been a Freudian slip! I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Following from you examples of cinematography and photography, the art form and the field are both called *painting* ([*Painting is my favorite form of art* = Живопись - это мой любимый вид искусства](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator#ru/en/%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C)).

But in English we lump all the visual arts together and commonly refer to them as simply **art.** You would speak of the *art* of Leonard da Vinci, who worked in both painting and sculpture. We have **art galleries**, rather than painting galleries despite paintings being the most exhibited artworks there.